# Forcing strong type checking with Fortran functions at compile time

Tags: fortran

I'm helping renovate a legacy code base in Fortran which has interface definitions for functions / subroutines.

The issue I am facing is that some of those interfaces are out of sync with the actual function definitions and the compiler (silverfrost) is not catching these at compile time. This leads to run time errors.

Ignoring the specific compiler I am using for now, does Fortran have a method for handling this without repeating the function definition? For example, in C#, Java etc. I can declare a function and call it from elsewhere in the project and the compiler makes sure the caller and target function are compatible.

Does GNU Fortran or the Intel Fortran compiler make this any less fragile?

Comment: Both those compilers have, IIRC, options to generate or check interfaces from files.  If you haven't, it may be worth searching for "interface" in each set of docs.

Comment: In the long term it is really better to use modules except some very specific situations.

Comment: Almost all the problems are the interfaces... With Ifort (intel) there is a switch like -generate -interfaces, which I use when I am not using a module.

Comment: If you already have explicit interface blocks, including them in caller and callee will invoke full compiler checking such as you ex o.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put procedures in MODULEs and USE the MODULEs, the compiler will check that procedures are called with the correct arguments.

Comment: Due to the naffness of the codebase this is not an immediate option but one I can work towards, thank you.